# Wording a proof for proving sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

How do you prove this? Isn't that A U B  will equal to B regardless because by definition, union of set A and B can either elements of A or B? And B will equal to the union of A or B because B is B or B is the parent of A? 
I understand the concept, I dont know if I explained it right but I understand it. Though how do you write a proof for it?
Thanks

Comment: These sorts of statements are almost always easiest to prove one direction at a time. Set equalities are often most easily shown by showing inclusion in both directions; and inclusions are shown by assuming membership in one side and trying to show membership in the other side.  So, for example, assume that $A\subset B$ and try to show that $A\cup B \subset B$, and then that $B\subset A\cup B$; then assume that $A\cup B =B$ and try to show that $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition

1. $A \subset B$ means that $x \in A$ implies $x \in B$
2. Similarly, $A = B$ means that $x \in A$ exactly if $x \in B$
3. Finally, $x \in A \cup B$ exactly if either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.

To show that $A \subset B$ implies $A \cup B = B$, you can thus argue as follows:

> Assume that $A \subset B$. We'll show that $x \in A \cup B$ exactly if $x \in B$, which proves $A \cup B = B$.
>
> If $x \in B$, then due to (3) $x \in A \cup B$.
>
> If $x \in A \cup B$ then again due to (3) either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. In the second case, we're done. In the first case, applying (1) also yields $x \in B$.

I leave the converse, i.e. that $A \cup B = B$ implies $A \subset B$ to you.